# The Equivalent Control to "asp:label" in Current VB.NET 2012 MVC4?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My background has been PHP with MySQL - and I do think I may be looking for an "echo" equivalent.

The intention is to have a `text field`, and then have the `submitted text` printed on the screen with e.g. `IsPostBack` and `on page load`.

The question is directed at the control `asp:label` to know what is used to have the equivalent function in VB.NET 2012.

**Differently formulated to specify what is intended:**

Basically, have the text submitted through the "textbox" and have it printed on the screen after "page load", perhaps "on page load". And then continue you further, by having the text saved in the database. (The first steps of a blog application.)

Comment: the "equivalent" to echo would be the shorthand tags `<%= variableName %>` in your aspx

Comment: Basically, have the text submitted through the "textbox" and have it printed on the screen after "page load", perhaps "on page load". And then continue you further, by having the text saved in the database. (The first steps of a blog application.) Notice: This writing has been a response.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [label component for web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx#Y300) still exists and is supported in the current version of .NET framework, which includes VB.NET. You should be able to populate that on postback.